# Variable PHP inside a Div Modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a PHP variavel named `$table`, and I want to show a Modal with this variable, but it's no working with

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content" value="'.$table.'">
</div>
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP values have to be emitted from server-side code.  HTML markup alone won't interpret them.  Something like this:

```
<div class="modal-content" value="<?php echo $table; ?>">
```

Comment: @user2999773: Any server-side code needs to be enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags in order for the PHP engine to evaluate it.  Anything outside those tags is delivered to the client as-is.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content" ><?php echo $table; ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content" ><?php if(isset($table)) { echo $table; } ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look my code please

```
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tic_bp_xprofile_data`";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
        if($row[3] == $select){
        $users[$i] = $row[2];
            $i++;}
            }
    $strSQL = "SELECT `ID`, `display_name`, `user_nicename` FROM `tic_users`";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $table .= '<th><p class="letrafiltro">Usuários</p></th>';
    for($aux =0 ; $aux<=$i; $aux++){
        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $table .= '<tr>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
            if($row[0]==$users[$aux])
                $table .='<td><a class="letrafiltro" href="http://ticomia.net.br/members/'.$row[2].'/">'.$row[1].'</a></td><td><a class="avatar" href="http://ticomia.net.br/members/'.$row[2].'/">'.get_avatar( $row[0], $default, $default ).'</a></td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';

            }


    echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" value="'$table'">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

everything is inside a php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code its working.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" value="<?php echo $table; ?>">
</div>
```